# schedule functions to execute at a specific time in psychopy asynchronously

Tags: psychopy

I am looking for a function to schedule a function call asynchronously, for example presenting an Image after 100ms, after 200ms and after 300ms and masking this image at 150ms 250ms and 350ms.

I am sure I can do this with delays, but I would prefer to do this asynchronously. I was able to do this in pyepl with timing.timedCall.

Answer (score 2):

To be genuinely 'aysnchronous' would need threads and, as Jonas suggests, these aren't safe for use with OpenGL (your graphics card doesn't know which thread a command is coming from and if its commands are executed out of order because of two interleaved threads then the results are unpredictable and could lead to a crash).

I'd naturally handle this with a function like

```
def checkTimes(t, listOfPermissible):
    for start,stop in listofPermissible:
       if start < t < stop:
           return True #we found a valid window
    return False #if we got here there was no valid window
```

and then in my script I'd have:

```
targetTimes = [[0.1, 0.15], [0.2, 0.25]]
maskTimes = [[0.18, 0.2], [0.28, 0.3]]

while continueTrial:
    t = trialClock.getTime()
    #check if we need target
    if checkTimes(t, targetTimes):
        target.draw()

    #check if we need mask
    if checkTimes(t, maskTimes):
        mask.draw()

    #drawing complete so flip the window
    win.flip()

    #check for response
    keys = event.getKeys()
    if keys:
        continueTrial = False
```

Jonas is also right though that you should use frame numbers instead of clock time if you have brief stimuli and care about them being precisely timed. As a cheeky example in the code above I've added some impossible times. For example 0.18 (180ms) which isn't possible with a 60Hz monitor. In the code above the 0.18 will effectively get rounded up to the next frame and the stimulus will appear at 183ms (11 frames into the block).

The rest of the logic above (checking in a list of start/stops) should still work just the same though.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's currently any way to do this. Previous attempts to run parts of psychopy stimulus presentation separate threads have failed, as far as I know. It's something about OpenGL not really being robust to this.

If there is a way to display stimuli asynchroniously, beware that visual stuff should really be timed in terms of number of frames rather than milliseconds for the durations you're considering. Presenting at e.g. 100 ms could just barely miss the 6th frame, thus shown the image on the 7th frame (after 116.7 ms). This is one of the points where I think many other stimulus presentation software packages mislead the user.

The ```psychopy.visual.Window.flip()`` method allows for timing using frames.